# Spree Rails app startup error 'Instance method "open" is already defined in Object'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, spree

This error happens when trying to run my Rails app in the production environment, but not dev:

> Instance method "open" is already defined in Object, use generic helper instead or set StateMachines::Machine.ignore_method_conflicts = true.

I'm relatively new to Rails and could use some help figuring out how to troubleshoot this.  What might be causing the error?  Where should I look, or what steps should I try in order to narrow down what's happening?

I recently upgraded from Ruby 2.2.2 to 2.2.4, but this error didn't appear immediately.  Other recently changes to the app have been confined to js, css, and ERB view files.

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.2.4'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3' #TODO settle on a non-edge Rails once enum prefixing is released
#gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

# group :development do
#   gem 'rails-dev-boost', :git => 'git://github.com/thedarkone/rails-dev-boost.git' #speed up development
#   gem 'rb-inotify', '>= 0.8.8'
# end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
#gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'spree', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '3-0-stable'

gem 'pg'
gem 'spree_i18n', git: 'git://github.com/spree/spree_i18n.git', branch: '3-0-stable'

gem 'spree_yadav_jewelry', :path => 'extensions/spree_yadav_jewelry'
gem 'spree_yadav_diamonds', :path => 'extensions/spree_yadav_diamonds'

gem 'has_scope'
gem 'aws-sdk-v1'
gem 'spree_static_content', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_static_content', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_contact_us', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_contact_us', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
```

Comment: Does the error screen point you to a specific line of code in a file? If so, could you post the code inside the file and tell us which line it points to?

Comment: Sorry, the error - both locally and on Heroku - don't give a line number or other trace.  Is there a way I can get this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only a warning message caused by state-machines gem.

This will be fixed in Spree 3.0.8. Sorry for the inconvenience!